# Minimal dummy content for attr.xml to silence "last" eclipse warning

Tags: android

When programming in eclipse I usually have almost all warnings enabled, since they help me spotting possible programming error or oversights on my side. I am then trying to write all my programs such that I **do not** get any warnings. However, with Android there is always one last warning and that I find annoying:

```
* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

package foo.bar.someappname;

public final class R {
    ...
    public static final class attr {  /* <<< this empty class creates a compiler warning */
    }
    ...
}
```

Apparently that attr-class refers to some optional style data that one could define in a file attr.xml. I do not want to define any own style(s), but what would be a minimal **dummy** content for attr.xml to have "something" appear in that attr-class so that this last warning is silenced?

Comment: couldn't you set an ignore flag for this file?  even if you modify R it will be deleted and recreated during compilation, as it is `automatically generated`

Comment: That's the point! The file will be constantly regenerated and thus just changing the R file (e.g. adding some comment or ignore flag to it) doesn't help. One has to create and add something to attr.xml so that after recreation the attr-class inside R is not empty. And disabling an eclipse warning for a particular file AFAIK isn't possible (other than via flags inside that file, but that doesn't work, as the file will regenerated...).

Comment: well, you could declare a custom view class (write something that extends `View`), and give it a custom attribute... That is the point of this class, maybe you find a use?  The point is for declaring something in XML instead of in your java code, something that the native android sdk doesn't recognize.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I read more on this style stuff and created an attr.xml file that reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="DummyAttribute_to_silence_compiler_warnings" format="reference|color" />
</resources>
```

This yields an attr.class inside the R.java file that looks as follows:

```
    public static final class attr {
        /** <p>May be a reference to another resource, in the form "<code>@[+][<i>package</i>:]<i>type</i>:<i>name</i></code>"
or to a theme attribute in the form "<code>?[<i>package</i>:][<i>type</i>:]<i>name</i></code>".
<p>May be a color value, in the form of "<code>#<i>rgb</i></code>", "<code>#<i>argb</i></code>",
"<code>#<i>rrggbb</i></code>", or "<code>#<i>aarrggbb</i></code>".
         */
        public static final int DummyAttribute_to_silence_compiler_warnings=0x7f010000;
    }
```

(that longish comment is added by the Android tools).

I would prefer something even shorter or without causing such a comment (which I don't even understand myself), but since that's an automatically generated file that's not meant for human consumption I can live with that...